# I got the error on sample project "Hello Word" on android - cocos2d

Tags: android

I have eclipse 3.7, cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.9.2, android-ndk-r7.

When I have create sample project but, it will get error "FORCE CLOSE"...

So is there any other thing i want to include on the project ?

Comment: What is your error in LogCat?

Comment: i got the error on LogCat - Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Comment: Error in LogCat : W/dalvikvm(223): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lorg/cocos2dx/application/ApplicationDemo;.<clinit>
W/dalvikvm(223): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lorg/cocos2dx/application/ApplicationDemo;)

Answer (score -1):

Your main application has a load static library method that is pointing to a nonexistent library, which means it has not found it. Recheck your makefiles for the correct module name. Also make sure they have compiled correctly with NDK beforehand and the .a and .so files are in the lib folder.